# SSRS REPORT BUILDER DATE PARAMETER as MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: sql, reporting-services, oracle-sqldeveloper, reportbuilder3.0

In Report Builder 3.0, I want to create a date parameter so that I can have the little calendar and have the end user click the calendar to select a date.  However, the data stored in the table is set to 2021-07-08 22:45:38.  I tried the TO_CHAR function, but then I can't put the little calendar as the data is not a date anymore.

Is it possible to convert the date time into regular MM/DD/YYYY and still have it be kept as date column so I can create that parameter?

The table is C_LAB, and the date column is LAB_DATE.  Like I said, I want to create parameter where user can select the date and have the option to use the calendar as well.

Comment: I don't use Report Builder. If it is a time component that bothers you, would `trunc(lab_date)` do any good (instead of `to_char`)? Because, TRUNC will "remove" time component (set it to midnight, actually, so value you posted would become 2021-07-08 00:00:00) and leave only date.

Answer (score 0):

2021-07-08 22:45:38 looks like a perfectly correct DateTime to me. Assuming that the `LAB_DATE` column datatype is DateTime then you could easily produce a "date only" version with.

```
SELECT *, CAST(LAB_DATE as Date) AS LAB_DATE2 FROM C_LAB
```

or if you want to use a date picker on the report and filter the results, the query would just be something like

```
SELECT * FROM C_LAB WHERE CAST(LAB_DATE as Date) = @myDatePickerParameter
```